# spl-stake-pool create-pool: RPC response error -32002

Tags: staking, command

I try to create a staking through this [article](https://www.quicknode.com/guides/solana-development/spl-tokens/how-to-create-liquid-staking-token) in Dev network.

But I meet problem when I use this command:

```
levi@LEVI-104-PC:/opt/solana/solana-liquid$ spl-stake-pool create-pool     --epoch-fee-numerator 5     --epoch-fee-denominator 100     --max-validators 10     --withdrawal-fee-denominator 1000     --withdrawal-fee-numerator 1
Creating reserve stake 7q1PWaLSGFoHZHd4Ez4cnamsNmcZ8v5FiJZxTRsMcYnS
Creating mint GXepp1kaLYNhfq7QbKxg1GoBou9Ky2iDeWtuo5JAA2tQ
Creating associated token account 7WWZhjoDY2DokRMByhSop4PfdUDvWmeDpU1XaWYVbeU8 to receive stake pool tokens of mint GXepp1kaLYNhfq7QbKxg1GoBou9Ky2iDeWtuo5JAA2tQ, owned by 8qo4xbcqFTrRoGmQFLPrhjJMKUtFiZkfgWmEcdTcgPwa
Creating pool fee collection account 7WWZhjoDY2DokRMByhSop4PfdUDvWmeDpU1XaWYVbeU8
Signature: 54VJd5851EchzY5frfezQRwvwPiYSLAJRn7ZhuVaKeCWemPqoaJvPG8AYhBGrwTKYTZyFAqkrDGjYA3RHYvn5HT
Creating stake pool HzDXnfVWps9h83CEVBWZcu5WoGPJFqnB7VTWSXn6kLhr with validator list 7s5bjR7ycV33b7LtFmhifcMuaMdKJeUxb3NyuF6bG3Ai
RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x3 [9 log messages]
```

The problem is that: RPC response error -32002: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 2: custom program error: 0x3 [9 log messages].

I use wsl2 in Windows11:

```
Ubuntu 20.04. 
spl-stake-pool-cli 1.0.0
solana-cli 1.16.28 (src:8a9f5026; feat:2294205250, client:SolanaLabs)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit annoying, but it looks like the program deployed to devnet and testnet is out-of-date, so you'll need to use an older version of the CLI to properly initialize your pool.

Please try using `spl-stake-pool-cli` v0.6.4 for devnet and testnet, but then you can safely use v1.0.0 for mainnet.

The problem stems from the required minimum amount of lamports in the reserve stake account, which was changed for v1.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try different config for fee arguments.

The error seems like [`CalculationFailure`](https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/8d311d34430ed9e223e46ff898cf81b222bfbc43/stake-pool/program/src/error.rs#L25)